# Problem with Deploy/HotDeploy using Netbeans 12.1 and Wildfly 18.0.1 for JAVAEE application

Tags: jsf, netbeans, wildfly, web-deployment, java-ee-8

Someone can help me with a problem? I am working with Netbeans 12.1, and before 12.0, and in both, some times, when I deploy my application, the process don't finish, but the server publish the app. I do not know why. Someone had the same problem? Thanks!

Netbeans 12.1 screen:

[image: Netbeans 12.1 screen]

Netbeans LOG:
..........................................................................

```
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in / marked with the position attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-editor-fold-ui-FoldingEditorSupport$F.instance, org-netbeans-modules-java-source-indexing-JavaBinaryIndexer$Factory-register.instance, org-netbeans-lib-editor-codetemplates-textsync-TextRegionManager$Highlighting$HLFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-lsp-client-bindings-MarkOccurrences$HighlightsLayerFactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-merge-builtin-visualizer-MergeHighlightsLayerFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-hints-infrastructure-SelectionHintsTaskFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-java-hints-infrastructure-EmbeddedHintsCollector$Factory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-core-CslCamelCaseInterceptor$Factory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-editor-overridden-ComputeAnnotations$FactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-spellchecker-SpellcheckerHighlightLayerFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-impl-DocumentFactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-diff-builtin-visualizer-editable-DiffHighlightsLayerFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-editor-fold-GsfFoldManagerTaskFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-textmate-lexer-SyntaxHighlighting$FactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-impl-highlighting-HLFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-hints-HighlightsLayerFactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-bracesmatching-BracesMatchHighlighting$Factory.instance, org-netbeans-lib-editor-hyperlink-HyperlinkOperation$HighlightFactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-javascript2-editor-embedding-JsEmbeddingProvider$Factory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-editor-semantic-MarkOccurrencesHighlighterFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-lib2-highlighting-Factory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-search-TextSearchHighlighting$FactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-hints-infrastructure-HintsTaskFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-refactoring-spi-impl-UndoableWrapper.instance, COSSynchronizingIndexer.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-hints-GsfHintsFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-navigation-BreadCrumbsTask$TaskFactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-url-HighlightURLs$FactoryImpl.instance, org-netbeans-modules-web-jsf-editor-index-JsfBinaryIndexer.instance, org-netbeans-modules-web-jsf-editor-index-JsfCustomIndexer$Factory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-tasklist-impl-TaskIndexerFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-hints-infrastructure-SuggestionsTaskFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-jumpto-file-FileIndexer$Factory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-navigation-CaretListeningFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-navigation-ClassMemberNavigatorSourceFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-csl-editor-semantic-SemanticHighlighterFactory.instance, org-netbeans-modules-spring-beans-index-SpringBinaryIndexer.instance], but some are: [EditorKit.instance]
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 1.821 for both org-netbeans-modules-gradle-customPopup.shadow and org-netbeans-modules-maven-customPopup.shadow
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in / marked with the position attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-lsp-client-bindings-CompletionProviderImpl.instance], but some are: [org-netbeans-modules-parsing-ui-WaitScanFinishedCompletionProvider.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-java-JavaCompletionProvider.instance, org-netbeans-modules-jshell-editor-HistoryCompletionProvider.instance, org-netbeans-modules-java-editor-javadoc-JavadocCompletionProvider.instance, org-netbeans-lib-editor-codetemplates-CodeTemplateCompletionProvider.instance, org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-persistence-editor-completion-JPACodeCompletionProvider.instance, org-netbeans-modules-websvc-editor-completion-WSCompletionProvider.instance, org-netbeans-modules-spellchecker-completion-WordCompletion.instance]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: CancelableTaskWrapper[task: org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsTask@59ce6a0d, phase: RESOLVED, priority: 500] : class org.netbeans.modules.java.source.JavaSourceAccessor$CancelableTaskWrapper ignored cancel for 629 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 201 binary roots took: 8.540 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/Downloads/roma-2.2.1/tag/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/Downloads/roma-2.2.1/tag/src/main/java took: 1 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/Downloads/roma-2.2.1/tag/src/test/java took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/Downloads/roma-2.2.1/tag/src/test/resources took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/RemovidaERP/src/main/resources took: 174 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/RemovidaERP/src/main/java took: 150 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/Removida-ERP/src/main/java took: 354 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/Removida-ERP/src/main/resources took: 45 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/Removida-ERP/src/test/java took: 73 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/RemovidaERP/src/test/java took: 49 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/Removida-ERP/src/main/webapp took: 232 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/Downloads/roma-2.2.1/tag/src/main/resources took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/RemovidaERP/src/test/resources took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/Removida-ERP/src/test/resources took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/Downloads/roma-2.2.1/tag/src/main/webapp took: 1 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/hgbasoni/NetBeansProjects/RemovidaERP/src/main/webapp took: 130 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 16 source roots took: 1.209 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: org.netbeans.modules.csl.navigation.BreadCrumbsTask@1fa1b5f2 : class org.netbeans.modules.csl.navigation.BreadCrumbsTask ignored cancel for 54 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.semantic.SemanticHighlighter@431618ea : class org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.semantic.SemanticHighlighter ignored cancel for 1.180 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 1.370 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 4 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /snap/netbeans/35/netbeans/webcommon/jsstubs/domstubs.zip took: 98 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /snap/netbeans/35/netbeans/webcommon/jsstubs/corestubs.zip took: 34 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /snap/netbeans/35/netbeans/webcommon/jsstubs/reststubs.zip took: 24 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 3 source roots took: 156 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (nu.validator.source.LocationRecorder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.GsfHintsProvider@636a88ec : class org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.GsfHintsProvider ignored cancel for 2.112 ms.
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 1.000 for both Projects/org-netbeans-modules-maven/Actions/org-netbeans-modules-debugger-ui-actions-DebugProjectAction.shadow and Projects/org-netbeans-modules-maven/Actions/org-netbeans-modules-payara-micro-action-reload.shadow
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.keyring.fallback.MasterPasswordEncryption]: Falling back to master password encryption; add -J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.keyring.level=0 to netbeans.conf to see why native keyrings could not be loaded
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.XMLDataObject@10c1a2b4[MultiFileObject@77d20d94[Actions/Help/master-help.xml]]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/dom4j/main/dom4j-2.1.1.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/dmr/main/jboss-dmr-1.5.0.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logging/main/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/marshalling/main/jboss-marshalling-2.0.9.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/marshalling/river/main/jboss-marshalling-river-2.0.9.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/remoting/main/jboss-remoting-5.0.15.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/threads/main/jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/xnio/main/xnio-api-3.7.3.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/xnio/nio/main/xnio-nio-3.7.3.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/controller/main/wildfly-controller-10.0.3.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/controller-client/main/wildfly-controller-client-10.0.3.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Adding /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/protocol/main/wildfly-protocol-10.0.3.Final.jar to the classpath
INFO [org.jboss.threads]: JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
INFO [org.jboss.remoting]: JBoss Remoting version 5.0.15.Final
INFO [org.xnio]: XNIO version 3.7.3.Final
INFO [org.xnio.nio]: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.3.Final
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]: Patching the issue #249135
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$SynchTask
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.doFindClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:209)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$SynchTask starting from ModuleCL@1a0dfa89[org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [ModuleCL@22e422d1[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common], ModuleCL@29d2850[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.dd], org.netbeans.JarClassLoader@675e918b, ModuleCL@60d3846e[org.netbeans.modules.java.platform.ui], ModuleCL@51bb61ce[org.netbeans.modules.extexecution.base], ModuleCL@4a21ada5[org.openide.text], ModuleCL@72ab3dd2[org.openide.awt], ModuleCL@5a972b38[org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.ui], ModuleCL@392b127[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.common], ModuleCL@308e244e[org.openide.dialogs], ...24 more]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.doFindClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:211)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(ClassWriter.java:1024)
Caused: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org/xnio/nio/WorkerThread$SynchTask not present
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(ClassWriter.java:1026)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory$WildFlyClassLoader$1.getCommonSuperClass(WildflyDeploymentFactory.java:153)
    at org.objectweb.asm.SymbolTable.addMergedType(SymbolTable.java:1202)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1299)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1197)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.computeAllFrames(MethodWriter.java:1610)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1546)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:769)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:649)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(ClassNode.java:465)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentFactory$WildFlyClassLoader.findClass(WildflyDeploymentFactory.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnio.build(NioXnio.java:233)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$Builder.build(XnioWorker.java:1191)
    at org.xnio.Xnio.createWorker(Xnio.java:481)
    at org.xnio.Xnio.createWorker(Xnio.java:463)
    at org.xnio.Xnio.createWorker(Xnio.java:450)
    at org.xnio.DefaultXnioWorkerHolder.lambda$static$0(DefaultXnioWorkerHolder.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.xnio.DefaultXnioWorkerHolder.<clinit>(DefaultXnioWorkerHolder.java:37)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.lambda$null$1(XnioWorker.java:172)
    at org.wildfly.common.context.ContextManager.getPrivileged(ContextManager.java:286)
    at org.wildfly.common.context.ContextManager.get(ContextManager.java:243)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.construct(EndpointImpl.java:243)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointBuilder.lambda$build$0(EndpointBuilder.java:150)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointBuilder.build(EndpointBuilder.java:150)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$2.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:135)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:110)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:263)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:101)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.ide.commands.WildflyClient.executeAsync(WildflyClient.java:347)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.ide.commands.WildflyClient.isServerRunning(WildflyClient.java:289)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.ide.WildflyStartServer$1.run(WildflyStartServer.java:215)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
INFO [org.wildfly.security]: ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.10.4.Final
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter arbitrarily from one of org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@6d78f375 and ModuleCL@7c8c5680[org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restlib] starting from SystemClassLoader[705 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.objectweb.asm.Frame arbitrarily from one of org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@6d78f375 and ModuleCL@7c8c5680[org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restlib] starting from SystemClassLoader[705 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter arbitrarily from one of org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@6d78f375 and ModuleCL@7c8c5680[org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restlib] starting from SystemClassLoader[705 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode arbitrarily from one of org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@6d78f375 and ModuleCL@7c8c5680[org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restlib] starting from SystemClassLoader[705 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode arbitrarily from one of org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@6d78f375 and ModuleCL@7c8c5680[org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restlib] starting from SystemClassLoader[705 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl]: Downloaded maven index file has size 0 (zipped). The usable space in /home/hgbasoni/snap/netbeans/common/cache/12.1 is 98.988.871.680.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl]: could not (re-)index prime-repo
java.net.UnknownHostException: repository.primefaces.org
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1002)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1160)
Caused: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Transfer failed for http://repository.primefaces.org/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1242)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1138)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.WagonHelper$WagonFetcher.retrieve(WagonHelper.java:220)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Transfer for nexus-maven-repository-index.properties failed; Transfer failed for http://repository.primefaces.org/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.WagonHelper$WagonFetcher.retrieve(WagonHelper.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.WagonHelper$WagonFetcher.retrieve(WagonHelper.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.downloadIndexProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.access$000(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater$IndexAdaptor.setProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:465)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:681)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:161)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.indexLoadedRepo(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:523)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.access$200(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:122)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl$3.run(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:654)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl$3.run(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:647)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.DefaultMutexImplementation.writeAccess(DefaultMutexImplementation.java:229)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:246)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.indexRepo(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:647)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.api.RepositoryIndexer.indexRepo(RepositoryIndexer.java:42)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.ProjectOpenedHookImpl$2.run(ProjectOpenedHookImpl.java:207)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
INFO [global]: JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -server -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,SBS-COL-TI-001 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.http.port=8080
INFO [FaceletsLibrarySupport]: Invalidating facelets libraries due to a library descriptor change.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment]
org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerException: Deployment timeout has exceeded.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.trackDeployProgressObject(TargetServer.java:987)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.deploy(TargetServer.java:672)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:221)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.DeploymentHelper.perform(DeploymentHelper.java:185)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:70)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:308)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
```

Comment: Could you share your netbeans log file ? Do you see anything in Wildfy's log ?

Comment: Nothing different in Wildfly log apparently. I will share the log files of both.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$SynchTask looks like the cause. Could you create a Jira for this , I'll try to fix it this week

Comment: Shure, I'm doing this right now. Thanks!

Comment: This is the link for JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4923